# Why am I getting ASP.NET MVC3 Razor Syntax Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm running the MVC3 RC2 with Razor in my VB.NET application.  I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting highlight errors in my markup.

Here are a couple of screenshots.

[image: debug 1]

[image: debug 2]

[image: debug 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the following in your `Views\Web.config` file:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: You appear to be correct. I was using the whitespace remover, and it looks like it buggered things up. `<host factoryType="Omari.Web.Mvc.WhiteSpaceCleaningMvcWebRazorHostFactory, WhiteSpaceCleanerForWebFormsAndMVC3"/>`

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Have you successfully combined "WhiteSpaceCleaner" with MVC3 without having such error? I have the same problem.